# Access to external resources files PHP

Tags: php, file, url

I would like to know if it is possible and how to access to external files in PHP. I am workink with CodeIgniter.

My project is located in /var/www/html/myproject, and I would like to access to files located in /home/me/myfile

I have the error

> the requested url was not found on this server

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I solved the problem by creating a symbolic link to my resources file so that I can access in the project root

Comment: if the webserver has permission to access the folder you're interested in, you can do `require "..\..\..\..\foo.php"` at the top of your php scripts.

Comment: I don't know if the server has the permission to access the folder. How to check it and how to set the permission ?

Comment: how are `/var/www/html/myproject` and `/home/me/myfile` related/associated?